# Dependent Junit test cases and test setUp

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am doing an integration test for a process using JUnit and there is a punch of processes that should be ran to set the environment to test any new feature, i do not want to setup the environment in every test method, so how can i set my environment in a setUp method?

I tried to include the configuration processes in the setUp method by adding the @BeforeAll and @BeforeEach and they did not help!

Comment: @Before should work just fine, what exactly is it that isn't working?

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using?